# Update database row after closing Link to SQL

Tags: c#, sql

have code where I get rows from a database, extract information which is added to different tables, and update the original row with links to the new primary keys. My problem is that after getting the rows I need to process, I close the connection. I do this because I have quite a bit of processing before resubmitting, and I need to add rows to other tables and get their auto-generated primary keys. Unfortunately, while all of the other data is being added correctly, my original rows are not updating.

First I get the rows I will be working with:

```
List<Procedure> result = new List<Procedure>();
using (dbContext db = new dbContext(SqlAccess.ConnectionString))
{
   var search =
      from Proc in db.GetTable<Procedure>()
      where Proc.ProcedureID == Guid.Empty
      select Proc;
   result = search.ToList<Procedure>();
}
```

I then add rows to different tables, update the Procedure row, and try to check in:

```
using (dbContext db = new dbContext(SqlAccess.ConnectionString))
{
   db.Findings.InsertAllOnSubmit(Findings);
   db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I'm sure I need to add something to my check-in code to say that I want to also check in my updates from the Procedure table, but I haven't been able to find what it is. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read your original rows again while the **new** context is active

Comment: @DrKoch - Thank you. I re-loaded the Procedure, and copied the old one over to the new one. After that, my table updated.